# Install Ruby On Rails Application on Windows IIS server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, iis-8

I'm going to install one basic ROR application on the windows IIS server.
I try many things and referred to some links which explain how to install ROR app on windows but it's not working for me.

Ruby version: 3.1.2
Rails version: 7.0.0

If I execute in the localhost of the windows machine, it's working fine but not working in the IIS server.

Project path : C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\bmw_test_project

I'm sharing my web.config file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
        <httpPlatform stdoutLogEnabled="true" processesPerApplication="1" stdoutLogFile="log\rails.log" startupTimeLimit="20" processPath="C:\Ruby31-x64\bin\ruby.exe" arguments="-S puma --env development --dir C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\bmw_test_project -p %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%">
            <environmentVariables>
              <environmentVariable name="RAILS_ENV" value="development" />
            </environmentVariables>
        </httpPlatform>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits>
                    <headerLimits>
                        <add header="maxQueryString" sizeLimit="2048" />
                    </headerLimits>
                </requestLimits>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I don't know where I'm lacking.

Can any one help me.

Comment: "It's not working" is not precise enough to help you in any way. What exactly is not working? Which error messages do you get? What behavior do you expect? What exactly do you see instead? Please edit your question and add a lot more details.

Comment: Can you confirm that Windows IIS is your only choice of server for Ruby on Rails?  As Ruby and Rails were originally intended for Linux, and most servers run Linux more securely and efficiently than Windows IIS you will find significantly more support in the Linux ecosystem for this issue.

Comment: How did you publish to iis? Do you get any error messages on iis? please post more details information about your requirement.